# Android - WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType :

Tags: android, wifi-direct

My app currently connects to a wifi access point in a P2P configuration. This small piece of code is producing a strange and uncommon warning that I'd like to get rid of.

I am getting this strange warning repeatedly upon running the app. My logcat:

```
10-12 07:33:00.540 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
10-12 07:33:00.550 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
10-12 07:33:00.570 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
10-12 07:33:00.590 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
10-12 07:33:00.610 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
10-12 07:33:00.620 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
10-12 07:33:00.630 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
10-12 07:33:00.640 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
10-12 07:33:00.650 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
10-12 07:33:00.660 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
10-12 07:33:00.670 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
10-12 07:33:00.680 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
10-12 07:33:00.700 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType : 
10-12 07:33:00.710 32352-32368/com.cantest.coriolis I/WifiManager: isAllowWifiWarning() -> isCscWifiEnableWarning : false ChinaNalSecurityType :
```

It will display these endlessly until I kill the app.

The code in question:

```
public static void connectToBlackBox() {
        connectThread = new Thread(() -> {

            while (!connectThread.isInterrupted()) {

                while (!wifiConnected) {
                    WifiManager mWifiManager = MainActivity.wifiManager;
                    WifiInfo mWifiInfo = mWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                    mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

                    if (getActiveNetworkName().contains(blackBoxNetworkSSID)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Found the correct SSID - " + mWifiInfo.getSSID());
                        DashboardFragment.wifiConnectedMsg(true);
                        wifiConnected = true;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Not the correct SSID - " + mWifiInfo.getSSID());
                        DashboardFragment.wifiConnectedMsg(false);
                    }
                }

                while (!socketConnected) {

                    if (socketConnected) {
                        break;
                    }
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "creating socket...");
                        socket = new Socket(IpAddress, port);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Socket connected. IP: " + socket.getInetAddress());
                        socketConnected = true;
                        listenForMessages();
                        return;
                    } catch (ConnectException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "ConnectException Error creating socket object:", e);
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ee) {}
                    } catch (IOException ee) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "IOException Error creating socket object:", ee);
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException eee) {}
                    }
                }
            }
            });
        connectThread.start();
        Log.i(TAG, "Connect thread started");
    }
```

Commenting out `mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);` seems to stop the endless stream of warnings. I can't find much on this message online, what exactly is this?